# Android: How to check if particular location is in the route?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps, android-navigation

I am creating an app where I have a requirement to check if a particular location is on the route? Eg. Lets say someone is travelling from A to C and I have to check if random B location falls in the route?

Answer (score 0):

If you use google map the you can check it from the response of below query. below is an example you can implement that one in your app customizing according to your need.

> http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=st.%20louis,mo&daddr=washington,dc%20to:chicago,il%20to:new%20york,ny